# Tcl/Tk with WebKit?

Tags: webkit, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it a realistic possibility to use WebKit (or any other available web engine) with Tcl/Tk to build the UI elements in a Tk top-level window based on HTML/CSS/JS?

I don't mean to build a web browser for viewing all internet content, but only to use it to display my content and store user input through interacting with a local SQLite database. I'd also like to be able to allow the user to update the database from a server when new information becomes available, but it is otherwise a desktop application requiring no connection to the internet.

I like Tk and may still use it only, but I'm having issues displaying multi-byte characters in RTL languages that I don't think can be resolved in the current version. I have this set up working as a web extension (which is mainly an application-specific UI library) using native-messaging to communicate with a C program compiled with the SQLite amalgamation file.  It works fairly well, but I prefer to not have to depend on a web browser and have been trying to move it to Tcl/Tk.

Is this a stupid thought to consider a web engine, and I ought to just learn GTK or Qt, or perhaps Qt WebKit or WebKitGTK? I'm using Linux but would like it to work on Windows also.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no ready-made solution for you, IIRC, but you may look at [WubTk](https://www.tclcommunityassociation.org/wub/proceedings/Proceedings-2010/SteveLanders/WubTk/wubtk.pdf) for inspiration and for some code reuse (jQuery based on Tkish widgets). [Entice](https://www.tcl.tk/community/tcl2007/papers/Steve_Landers/Entice.pdf) for some instructions on how to use a standalone browser as a Tk widget under X11.

Comment: There's been things done a few times, but reputedly the builds are horrifically complicated and the projects to do it were often commercial. I never needed it myself — my projects are happy with just telling a browser to open a standard URL — so I never looked into the details.

Comment: @mrcalvin Thanks for the links. The Entice document is what I was considering, especially the first approach they didn't take but apparently TkGecko tried for sometime. Perhaps WebKit would be better than Gecko was and I don't think Quantum is embeddable. I don't want to display Tk widgets in web pages, just HTML; so, maybe I'd be better off using Tcl as a local server.  I wonder if embedding a web engine would be any better than a local server in terms of size and resource consumption.  It all appears to be way beyond my skill level and knowledge.